# can't download file from ftp with ftp_get (no error)

Tags: php, ftp, download

I'm trying to download file from ftp, but whatever i tried i couldn't download any file from ftp and it is not giving any error.

My code fetching file names from database and compares these file names with existing ftp file(names). If file name exist on ftp i want to download this file to my local-destination folder.
I can read ftp file names but i can't download them. Hope you can help me.

**Here is my code**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$ftp_server = "xx.xx.y12.34"; //server
$bt = ftp_connect($ftp_server); // connect to ftp
$username = "myusername"; $pass = "mypass"; //username and password
$connection = ftp_login($bt, $username, $pass); // login ftp with username and password
ftp_pasv($bt, true);

if ((!$bt) || (!$connection)) {
  echo "failed";
  exit;
}else {
  $path = "/1_Swatch Files/LG Swatches/";
  $destination_folder = "/home/faruk/lasenza/media/color_samples/";
  // mysql connection codes..
  $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query); // fetch file names from database
  $contents_on_server = ftp_nlist($bt, $path);

foreach($results as $result){
      $check_file_exist = $result["CLR_CODE"].".gif";
    if(in_array($check_file_exist, $contents_on_server)) {        
      $server_file = $result["CLR_CODE"].".gif";
      if (ftp_get($bt, $destination_folder , $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
          echo 'Succeeded';
      }else{
          echo "There was a problem";
      } 
      break;
  } 
 }


}
```

Comment: Check the apache error log.